# I have to Send a Json Object from Android App to Azure Rest API , Look into my Code help me ,works other API's

Tags: android, json, azure-api-apps

I want to send the json object
{
  "PersonID" : "124",
  "DeviceID": "123",
"ExpID": "1234",
  "ID" : "4566"
}
 to particular Azure Rest API URL

Ive Tried With the Code Given below it Works for URL-http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet but not for my AZURE REST API's URL

MainActivity.java

```
private String httpPost(String myUrl) throws IOException, JSONException 
   {
    String result = "";

    URL url = new URL(myUrl);

    // 1. create HttpURLConnection
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    // 2. build JSON object
    JSONObject jsonObject = buidJsonObject();

    // 3. add JSON content to POST request body
    setPostRequestContent(conn, jsonObject);

    // 4. make POST request to the given URL
    conn.connect();

    // 5. return response message
    return conn.getResponseMessage()+"";
}

private class HTTPAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            try {
                return httpPost(urls[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error!";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //tvResult.setText(result);
    }
}

public void send(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // perform HTTP POST request

        new HTTPAsyncTask().execute("URL");
}

private JSONObject buidJsonObject() throws JSONException {

    String w= "test";
    String a=  "ABCD";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("PersonID",token);
    jsonObject.put("DeviceID", Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    jsonObject.put("ExpID", w);

    jsonObject.put("ID", a);



    return jsonObject;
}

private void setPostRequestContent(HttpURLConnection conn, JSONObject jsonObject) throws IOException {

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
    Log.i(MainActivity.class.toString(), jsonObject.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="send"
    android:text="Send"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="266dp" />
```

i want Token id , android id to be sent to Azure REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to help you out but I need a little more information from you. For instance, is your code snippet throwing any errors? What does `conn.getRepsonseMessage()` return? Also, you're indicating you're doing a post to that URL. Clicking on the link I do get JSON back but got a 500 error when I attempted to do a POST which leads me to believe that endpoint only accepts GETs.

The steps I would follow is use a tool like fiddler to make a POST to your Azure API endpoint and ensure there's no errors on that side if you're getting 200s back.

Comment: Actually conn.getresponseMessage() returns nothing and the JSON Data {PersonID is integer and Rest Others are Strings , i want display the json Response , will get msg & Status

Comment: It returns nothing against http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet or your Azure REST API? http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet doesn't accept the POST verb so you should be getting an HTTP exception with status code of 500 on `conn.connect();`

Comment: i have a another REST API from which is little bit Confidential , i somehow manage send json and Got Response http200 ok ,  that REST API responses the Same json with Two additional fields in JSON , now am having Trouble how get the response and how to display them textview . please help

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/) if you haven't already. Pass your response string into `JSONObject(<response text>)` to get a JSON object. Once you get your JSON object, you can bind the property (or properties) as outlined in [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/).